# `null` is treated as String?

Tags: java, string, nullpointerexception

```
String s = null;
s = s + "hai";
System.out.println(s);
```

Output:

```
nullhai
```

Thought this would throw me NPE.

What is the fundamental logic behind

- not throwing NPE while using `+` (concatenation)
- throwing NPE while using `.`

Comment: Language spec defines it to work like that; see: http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java/fclass/ch02_03.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For , `s = s + "hai";`
Internally, `String.valueOf(null)` will be called. That method will convert `null` to `"null"`.

Byte code :

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[])   throws java.lang.Exception;
    0:   aconst_null
  //some code
   10:  invokestatic    #27; //Method java/lang/String.valueOf:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String;// check this line
// some other code
       27:  return
```

Answer (score 3):

No it wont.Compiler replaces String concatenation with `StringBuilder` operations which doesn't give null pointer exception.Compiler does all this backend and saves our time of writing boiler-plate code.Actually there is no such thing as `String` concatenation as String is **immutable**

Decompiled code:-

```
    String s = null; 
    s = (new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(s))).append("hai").toString(); 
    System.out.println(s);
```

So,the answer to your question.

1. Compiler internally changes `+` concatenation operations using `StringBuilder` and `String.valueOf` operations.So the compiler makes sure that null cases would be handled
2. While using a `.` operator on a `String` instance,you invoke methods defined in a `String` instance such as `String.concat(String str)`which will give a NullPointerException if your `String` instance is null

Comment: I think you should emphasize more on `String.valueOf()` being called internally. Without valueOf(), you will get an NPE. :)

Comment: @TheLostMind I think i answered how String concatenation works using + operator,but yes String.valueOf is important

Comment: Wow, so it was useless for me to convert s += "some text \n"; (10 of these lines) into a string builder? The compiler does that already to prevent so many strings from being initialized?

Answer (score 1):

`NullPointerException` is only thrown if you try to call a method on a reference which is `null` (or trying to access a field of it; or you manually throw a `NullPointerException`).

This does not happen in your case because your `null` reference will be converted to a `"null"` `String`, no method will be called on the `s` local variable.

So for example:

```
String s = null;
boolean isNull = s == null; // This is ok, just testing the value of s
s.toString();               // NPE, s is null
```

Also note that static fields can be accessed even if variable is `null`:

```
s.valueOf(12);             // THIS IS ALSO OK, valueOf(int) is static
// It is equivalent to:
String.valueOf(12);
```

Comment: This is interesting !! For static methods, will the reference points to class ? I mean; `s.XXX` is equivalent `String.XX` ?