# Boolean.valueOf() produces NullPointerException sometimes

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, boolean

I have this code:

```
package tests;

import java.util.Hashtable;

public class Tests {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Hashtable<String, Boolean> modifiedItems = new Hashtable<String, Boolean>();

        System.out.println("TEST 1");
        System.out.println(modifiedItems.get("item1")); // Prints null
        System.out.println("TEST 2");
        System.out.println(modifiedItems.get("item1") == null); // Prints true
        System.out.println("TEST 3");
        System.out.println(Boolean.valueOf(null)); // Prints false
        System.out.println("TEST 4");
        System.out.println(Boolean.valueOf(modifiedItems.get("item1"))); // Produces NullPointerException
        System.out.println("FINISHED!"); // Never executed
    }
}
```

My problem is that I don't understand why *Test 3* works fine (it prints `false` and doesn't produce `NullPointerException`) meanwhile *Test 4* throws a `NullPointerException`. As you can see in tests *1* and *2*, `null` and `modifiedItems.get("item1")` are equals and `null`.

The behavior is the same in Java 7 and 8.

Comment: modifiedItems.get("item1") this is null, you are aware of that, but you assume that passing this to a valueOf will not end up in a NPE?

Comment: @Stultuske: It's a valid question, given that just two lines above passing a literal `null` to the same function *doesn't* generate an NPE! There's a good reason for it, but it's certainly confusing at first sight :-)

Comment: I'm impressed. This is the most interesting null pointer exception question I've seen in years.

Comment: @Jeroen this isn't a dupe of [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352791/why-comparing-integer-with-int-can-throw-nullpointerexception-in-java). Whilst it is true that unboxing is common to the two problems, there is no comparison going on here. The key thing about this question is that it occurs because of the way overloads are resolved; and that's quite a different thing from how `==` is applied.

Answer (score 181, accepted):

You've got to look carefully at which overload is being invoked:

- `Boolean.valueOf(null)` is invoking [`Boolean.valueOf(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-). This doesn't throw an `NPE` even if supplied with a null parameter.
- `Boolean.valueOf(modifiedItems.get("item1"))` is invoking [`Boolean.valueOf(boolean)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#valueOf-boolean-), because `modifiedItems`'s values are of type `Boolean`, which requires an unboxing conversion. Since `modifiedItems.get("item1")` is `null`, it is the unboxing of that value - not the `Boolean.valueOf(...)` - which throws the NPE.

---

The rules for determining which overload is invoked are [pretty hairy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2), but they roughly go like this:

- In a first pass, a method match is searched for without allowing boxing/unboxing (nor variable arity methods).

  - Because `null` is an acceptable value for a `String` but not `boolean`, `Boolean.valueOf(null)` is matched to `Boolean.valueOf(String)` in this pass;
  - `Boolean` isn't an acceptable for either `Boolean.valueOf(String)` or `Boolean.valueOf(boolean)`, so no method is matched in this pass for `Boolean.valueOf(modifiedItems.get("item1"))`.
- In a second pass, a method match is searched for, allowing boxing/unboxing (but still not variable arity methods).

  - A `Boolean` can be unboxed to `boolean`, so `Boolean.valueOf(boolean)` is matched for `Boolean.valueOf(modifiedItems.get("item1"))` in this pass; but an unboxing conversion has to be inserted by the compiler to invoke it: `Boolean.valueOf(modifiedItems.get("item1").booleanValue())`
- (There's a third pass allowing for variable arity methods, but that's not relevant here, as the first two passes matched these cases)

Comment: Could code be more clear if we use `Boolean.valueOf(modifiedItems.get("item1").booleanValue())` in source code instead of `Boolean.valueOf(modifiedItems.get("item1"))` ?

Comment: @CausingUnderflowsEverywhere not really - it is really hard to see that `.booleanValue()` buried in the expression. Two observations: 1) auto(un)boxing is a deliberate feature of Java to remove syntactic cruft; doing it yourself is possible, but not idiomatic; 2) this doesn't help you at all - it certainly doesn't stop the problem from occurring, nor does it give any extra info when the failure does occur (the stack trace would be identical, because the executed code is identical).

Comment: @CausingUnderflowsEverywhere it is better to use tooling to highlight the issues, e.g. intellij would earn you about potential NPE here.

Answer (score 13):

Since `modifiedItems.get` returns a `Boolean` (which is **not** castable to a `String`), the signature that would be used is [`Boolean.valueOf(boolean)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#valueOf-boolean-), where the `Boolean` is outboxed to a primitive `boolean`. Once `null` is returned there, the outboxing fails with a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 11):

### Method signature

The method `Boolean.valueOf(...)` has two signatures:

1. `public static Boolean valueOf(boolean b)`
2. `public static Boolean valueOf(String s)`

Your `modifiedItems` value is `Boolean`. You cannot cast `Boolean` to `String` so consequently the first signature will be chosen

### Boolean unboxing

In your statement

```
Boolean.valueOf(modifiedItems.get("item1"))
```

which can be read as

```
Boolean.valueOf(modifiedItems.get("item1").booleanValue())
```

However, `modifiedItems.get("item1")` returns `null` so you'll basically have

```
null.booleanValue()
```

which obviously leads to a `NullPointerException`

Comment: Incorrect wording, thanks for pointing and answer is updated following your feedback. Apologies, I haven't seen your answer while writing and I see that mine looks like yours. Should I remove my answer to avoid confusion for OP?

Comment: Don't delete it on my account. Remember, this isn't a zero-sum game: people can (and do) upvote multiple answers.

Answer (score 3):

As Andy already very well described the reason of `NullPointerException`:

which is due to Boolean un-boxing:

```
Boolean.valueOf(modifiedItems.get("item1"))
```

get converted into:

```
Boolean.valueOf(modifiedItems.get("item1").booleanValue())
```

at runtime and then it throw `NullPointerException` if `modifiedItems.get("item1")` is null.

Now I would like to add one more point here that un-boxing of the following classes to their respective primitives can also produce `NullPointerException` exception if their corresponding returned objects are null.

1. byte - Byte
2. char - Character
3. float - Float
4. int - Integer
5. long - Long
6. short - Short
7. double - Double

Here is the code:

```
    Hashtable<String, Boolean> modifiedItems1 = new Hashtable<String, Boolean>();
    System.out.println(Boolean.valueOf(modifiedItems1.get("item1")));//Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

    Hashtable<String, Byte> modifiedItems2 = new Hashtable<String, Byte>();
    System.out.println(Byte.valueOf(modifiedItems2.get("item1")));//Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

    Hashtable<String, Character> modifiedItems3 = new Hashtable<String, Character>();
    System.out.println(Character.valueOf(modifiedItems3.get("item1")));//Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

    Hashtable<String, Float> modifiedItems4 = new Hashtable<String, Float>();
    System.out.println(Float.valueOf(modifiedItems4.get("item1")));//Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

    Hashtable<String, Integer> modifiedItems5 = new Hashtable<String, Integer>();
    System.out.println(Integer.valueOf(modifiedItems5.get("item1")));//Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

    Hashtable<String, Long> modifiedItems6 = new Hashtable<String, Long>();
    System.out.println(Long.valueOf(modifiedItems6.get("item1")));//Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

    Hashtable<String, Short> modifiedItems7 = new Hashtable<String, Short>();
    System.out.println(Short.valueOf(modifiedItems7.get("item1")));//Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

    Hashtable<String, Double> modifiedItems8 = new Hashtable<String, Double>();
    System.out.println(Double.valueOf(modifiedItems8.get("item1")));//Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: "Converted into ... at runtime" it's converted to that at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

A way to understand it is when `Boolean.valueOf(null)` is invoked, java is precisely being told to evaluate null.

However, when `Boolean.valueOf(modifiedItems.get("item1"))` is invoked, java is told to obtain a value from the HashTable of object type Boolean, but it doesn't find the type Boolean it finds a dead end instead (null) even though it expected Boolean. The NullPointerException exception is thrown because the creators of this part of java decided this situation is an instance of something in the program going wrong that needs the programmer's attention. (Something unintended happened.)

In this case it is more the difference between deliberately declaring that you intended the null to be there, and java finding a missing reference to an object (null) where an object was intended to be found.

See more information about NullPointerException in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25721181/4425643

Comment: If someone can help improve this answer, I was thinking of a word that refers to the programmer writing something with clear intention, with no ambiguity